# sum of importrange from different google sheet links

Tags: google-sheets-formula

=sum(
IMPORTRANGE(AB2,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB3,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB4,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB5,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB6,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB7,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB8,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB9,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB10,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB11,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB12,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB13,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB14,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"),
IMPORTRANGE(AB15,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"))

how can i shortened this formula?

i've tried
=sum(
IMPORTRANGE(AB2:AB15,"Copy of Nutrional Status!c10"))

but not all data where cell values where added

note: cells AB2:AB!5 contain the google sheet links

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en)

```cpp
=REDUCE(,AB2:AB15,LAMBDA(tot,ss,tot+SUM(IMPORTRANGE(ss,"Copy of Nutrional Status!C10"))))
```